# how to use next_permutation

Tags: c++, permutation

I'm trying to get an arrangement of tic tac toe boards. So I have the following code:

```
// 5 turns for x if x goes first
std::string moves = "xxxxxoooo";

do {
    std::cout << moves << std::endl;
} while ( std::next_permutation(moves.begin(), moves.end()) );
```

But it only outputs the original string once. I'm assuming that each character has to be unique. What's a way I can do this?

Comment: Try starting with the opposite order, `next_permutation` produces them in lexicographical order, and what you have is the lexicographically last.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`std::next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) returns the next permutation in lexicographic order, and returns `false` if the first permutation (in that order) is generated.

Since the string you start with (`"xxxxxoooo"`) is actually the last permutation of that string's characters in lexicographic order, your loop stops immediately.

Therefore, you may try sorting `moves` before starting to call `next_permutation()` in a loop:

```
std::string moves = "xxxxxoooo";
sort(begin(moves), end(moves));

while (std::next_permutation(begin(moves), end(moves)))
{
    std::cout << moves << std::endl;
}
```

Here is a [*live example*](http://ideone.com/sStfA1).