# Next highest number

Tags: math

On re-arranging digits in number `1862` next highest number is `2168`

On re-arranging digits in number `22405` next highest number is `22450`

What is an algorithm for finding next highest number?

Comment: Just what do you mean by "next highest number"? Do you mean the next highest of all the numbers that can be gotten by rearranging the decimal digits of the original number? And by "mathematical process" do you mean an algorithm or code in some computer language or something else? I do have such code, in Object Pascal (Delphi), and would love to translate that to Python, but you need to clarify what you want. You also need to tell us the work you have done on this problem so far and show any code you have made. This is not a homework-answering service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm to find next greater permutation of a given string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622532/algorithm-to-find-next-greater-permutation-of-a-given-string)

Comment: that's what [`std::next_permutation`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16680391/995714) is for

Answer (score 2):

Here is a summary of an algorithm that does what you want. If you want more details, code, or a proof of the correctness of the algorithm, show us more of what you have done so far.

Let's use `1862` as an example. Scan the digits of that number from the right-most digit to the left until you find a consecutive pair of digits where the left digit is smaller than the right digit. In this case that is the `18`. Let's call that left digit the "pivot" position (`1` here). You will now rearrange the digits in the number starting with that pivot. Replace the pivot with the next-larger digit that is anywhere to the right of it (`2` in this case). Then after that digit, place all the other digits that used to be at or right of the pivot (`186` in this case) in ascending order (`168` here). The result is your answer `2168`.

In your other example `22405` you scan back and stop at `05`. You replace the `0` with the `5` then put the other digit(s), `0` in this case, after it in increasing order. So you leave the `224` alone and end up with `22450`.

If, in your backwards scan, you do not find any consecutive pair of digits where the left digit is smaller than the right digit, then there is no larger number with those digits.

There is a trick to speed up the placement of the digits in increasing order, but I'll leave that to you.